# What do "back east" and "heat bait" in the sentence below mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

It's a sentence from an Rpg video game. There was this guy who was hurt and one of the dialog choices was a question "You want me to call an ambulance" and this is the answer he gave me:

"What? No! I've got a record **back east**. **I'm heat bait**. Don't touch that phone! No God Damn Cops!"

What does this sentence mean (especially the bold parts)?

Comment: Not even urban dictionary has this, which suggests that it is "slang" invented by the author of the game, and has not real use.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with "heat bait," and don't see relevant search results for it. But we can piece things together:

- **Heat** can have a colloquial meaning of *trouble with authority or the law* ("If we get caught, I won't take the heat!")
- **Bait** can [mean](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bait) something that attracts another thing, as fish bait attracts fish, so perhaps the character is saying he attracts trouble with the law.
- **A record**, in this case, is a [criminal record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_record); the man is saying he was convicted of a crime that is on record.
- **Back east** refers to a location (if this is in the United States, then the [eastern part of the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_United_States)). Perhaps the character came west to be less likely to be recognized.

Comment: Heat can also mean the use or presence of a gun. If the person had a sufficiently bad police record, local police might approach him with guns drawn. 'Packing heat' means 'carrying a gun'.

Comment: There's a chance "heat bait" has some specific meaning in the world of Vampire: The Masquerade, but I haven't played the game myself to know.

Comment: Since the character says "No goddamn cops!" it seems very likely to this US English speaker that the character means just "police" when he says "heat".

Comment: "The heat" can also mean "the police" *directly*.